# Не работает выбор пункта в контекстном меню

Tags: android

В фрагменте я создаю два метода для реализации контекстного меню:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_1);
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 2, Menu.NONE, R.string.context_menu_item_3);
}

@Override
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:
            break;
        case 2:
            break;
    }

    return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
}
```

Но на строке: `return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);` мне выдает ошибку:

> Cannot resolve method 'onMenuItemSelected(int, android.view.Menu)'

В `Activity` это работает, но в фрагменте... Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо `onMenuItemSelected()` надо использовать `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

```
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.a_item:
                Log.i("ContextMenu", "Item 1a was chosen");
                return true;
            case R.id.b_item:
                Log.i("ContextMenu", "Item 1b was chosen");
                return true;
        }
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Всё это находится по первой [ссылке](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2013/06/09/display-context-menu-fragment/) на запрос

> [context menu android fragment](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=context%20menu%20android%20fragment)

Comment: Как бы не хотел Вас огорчать, но я даже нашел это на русском, раньше чем Вы ответили :)).

Comment: Эм...Т.е. вы сначала вопрос задали, а потом в гугл пошли?..

Comment: Ну... Не совсем. Сначала я не нашел, задал вопрос и только потом нашел.

Comment: Начинайте пробовать гуглить на англосаксонском)

Comment: Эх... Уже приходится :(.

Comment: Верните мне мой Паскаль, где гуглить вообще не приходилось :D.